# How to right click on Raspbian from Mac keyboard when connected via VNC?

Tags: vnc, macos

How can I right-click on Raspbian from a Mac keyboard when I am connected via VNC?

I have tried `Ctrl + Click` and some other obvious choices without success. `ctrl+click` on a link in the browser, for example, opens up the link in a new tab instead of opening a context menu as I would expect a right-click to do.

Comment: What is wrong with Right-click on your mouse?

Comment: Apple's 'right click' options are [covered here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207700). If those don't work, it's your VNC configuration. That question has been asked many, many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapping the **trackpad** with two fingers may work.

If it doesn't, then tap the ‘mouse’ icon from the little navigation bar at the top of the main VNC screen. Then you'll see a mirrored L kinda thing on the lower-right corner of the screen. It's divided into three parts. **The far right section** sends a right click signal.

I hope it works. Cheers!